# php cookie with % in value

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

as php noob I have a problem with php setcookie. I try to achive a cookie which value is "bid_1%257C1544538505%257Ced2d154bb51e2a989fb30fe4250ce602" with php.
This I tried so far... .

```
$cookieName = 'test';
$value =    'bid_1%7C1544538505%7Ced2d154bb51e2a989fb30fe4250ce602';
$setcookie($cookieName, $value, time()+3600);
```

What I get is a cookie with a value of:

```
  bid_1%257C1544538505%257Ced2d154bb51e2a989fb30fe4250ce602
```

How can I achive a correct value and prevent php from transforming "%". Many Thanks in advance.

I tried without success

```
 $value =    'bid_1%%7C1544538505%%7Ced2d154bb51e2a989fb30fe4250ce602';// and
 $value =    'bid_1\%7C1544538505\%7Ced2d154bb51e2a989fb30fe4250ce602';
```

Comment: I suggest looking at [php setrawcookie](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.setrawcookie.php) which might resolve your problem

Comment: @JérômeB this was exactly, what resolved my problem. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the root problem is that [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) encodes your value, therefore some characters like `%` are encoded as `%25`

### Solution

[setrawcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setrawcookie.php) doesn't have this feature and therefore returns the result you want

Comment: No, the root problem is that they are trying to re-encode something that they already ran through `urlencode()`. (That's not to say your answer won't work of course.)

Answer (score 2):

> What I get is a cookie with a value of

No. What you quoted there is a representation of the actual value. What is stored on the client, and is returned in subsequent requests is the same value you passed as an argument to setcookie().